# How do I update page title with dash callback?

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I need to update page title (that is shown on tab name) with dash callback. Usually you can update any html element with a callback.

```py
@dash.callback(
    Output('id-here','output-property'),
    Input('input-element','input-property'))
def blah()
    return ('XYZ')
```

However, what I need is to update the page title, which has no html element id. Tried including `html.Title("ABC",id='abc')` in page content and use callback to update element `abc`. But it obviously doesn't work because the element in not in `<head>` of whole html page.

If I update as in `dash.title='New tab title'`, this will only reflect when page is refreshed. I need to do this will callbacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [clienside callback](https://dash.plotly.com/clientside-callbacks), for example :

```py
app.clientside_callback(
    """
    function(data) {
        document.title = 'new title';
        return 'XYZ';
    }
    """,
    Output('id-here', 'output-property'),
    Input('input-element', 'input-property'),
    prevent_initial_call=True
)
```